# .htaccess syntax redirect one domain to another without matching?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I'm looking to do:

Redirect example.com/(any-number) to example2.com/landing-page

example.com/(any-number) has hundreds of articles all of which end in a number. I'm not looking to match the number on my other site so much as direct people to a single landing page.

Current htaccess looks like this:

```
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://my-other-site.com/landing-page [L,R=301]
```

In the htaccess file in the document root of the "my-site.com" site.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to work. Edited my original post to show what my htaccess file looks like.